getting zip extraction issue on aws lambda springboot api
I am getting entry.getName() empty on lambda logs but valid filename on local debugging. Please help me here, I am stuck.
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> deployProduct1(MultipartFile file, Map<String, String> headers) throws IOException {
    File tempDir = createTempDirectory();

    // Extract the zip file
    List<String> extractedXmlFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        unzipFile(file, tempDir);
        // Access and process XML files
        
        findAndProcessXmlFiles(tempDir, extractedXmlFiles);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build();
    } finally {
        // Delete the extracted files
        deleteDirectory(tempDir);
    }

    // Return the list of extracted XML files
    return ResponseEntity.ok(extractedXmlFiles);
}

private void findAndProcessXmlFiles(File directory, List<String> extractedXmlFiles) {
    String MethodName = "findAndProcessXmlFiles():::::";
    System.out.println(MethodName+"starts");
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // Recursively search within subdirectories
                findAndProcessXmlFiles(file, extractedXmlFiles);
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
                // Save XML file to MongoDB
                saveXmlToMongoDB(file);
                extractedXmlFiles.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(MethodName+"ends");
}

private File createTempDirectory() throws IOException {
    String MethodName = "createTempDirectory():::::";
    System.out.println(MethodName+"starts");
    String prefix = "tempDir-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    Path tempDirPath = Files.createTempDirectory(prefix);

    if (!Files.exists(tempDirPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(tempDirPath);
    }
    System.out.println(MethodName+"ends");
    return tempDirPath.toFile();
}

private void unzipFile(MultipartFile file, File destDir) throws IOException {
    String MethodName = "unzipFile():::::";
    System.out.println(MethodName+"starts");
    try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream())) {
        System.out.println(MethodName+"inside try");
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(MethodName+"inside while::::+"+entry.getName());
            File entryDestination = new File(destDir, entry.getName());
            System.out.println(MethodName+"entryDestination :::"+entryDestination);
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(MethodName+"inside if :::"+entry.isDirectory());
                entryDestination.mkdirs();
            } else {
                System.out.println(MethodName+"inside else :::"+entry.isDirectory());
                Files.copy(zipInputStream, entryDestination.toPath());
            }
            System.out.println(MethodName+"bfore  zipInputStream.closeEntry :::");
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        }
        System.out.println(MethodName+"after  while  :::");
    }
    System.out.println(MethodName+"ends");
}

private void saveXmlToMongoDB(File xmlFile) {
    String MethodName = "saveXmlToMongoDB():::::";
    System.out.println(MethodName+"starts");
    try {
        // Connect to MongoDB
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = storageServiceManager
                .getCollection(IStorageConstants.DEPLOYEMENT_COLLECTION);

        // Read XML file content
        String xmlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(xmlFile.toPath()));

        // Create a document and insert into MongoDB
        Document document = new Document("filename", xmlFile.getName())
                .append("content", xmlContent);
        collection.insertOne(document);

        // Close MongoDB connection
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(MethodName+"ends");
}

private void deleteDirectory(File directory) {
    String MethodName = "deleteDirectory():::::";
    System.out.println("inside "+MethodName);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(file);
            } else {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("deleted "+MethodName);
    directory.delete();
}

inside method

unzipFile

I am printing lines, but when I print entry.getName() on lambda logs, I am getting empty string.
It's the same file that I am using on my local machine. But there I am getting valid file names.

Most of the code is unrelated to the issue and not worth putting here. You can simply grab a copy of the ZIP by using Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), somepathtozip) and do your own checks with that ZIP and post just the call as void unzipFile(InputStream file, File destDir)

I found the solution,
in the api gateway i have added application/data-form in binaries
